# Array filling with malloc supposedly allocating less memory than needed

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'd like to know why I'm having this behavior:

This is the code that I'm using:

```
matriz2= (float**) malloc (sizeof(float**));
    for (int m=0;m<36;m++)
{
    matriz2[m]=(float *) malloc(36*sizeof(float*));
}


for (int k=0;k<36;k++)
{
        for (int l=0;l<36;l++)
        {
            matriz2[k][l]=i;
            i++;
            printf("%f\n ",matriz2[k][l]);
        }
}
```

I've checked some things about the memory allocation that malloc does.

The following code runs nice if instead matriz2[m]=(float *) malloc(36*sizeof(float*)); I put (float *) malloc(35*sizeof(float*));

But that doesn't happen if I do it with 34.

I've also checked that the following code works, indeed it works up to changing all 3s for 4s, with 5 it fails:

```
matriz2= (float**) malloc (sizeof(float**));
    for (int m=0;m<3;m++)
{
    matriz2[m]=(float *) malloc(sizeof(float*));
}


for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
{
        for (int l=0;l<3;l++)
        {
            matriz2[k][l]=i;
            i++;
            printf("%f\n ",matriz2[k][l]);
        }
}
```

Although from what I understand from malloc it shouldn't be able to fill the array and a segmentation fault should happen.

Why can I fill the array this way?

Thanks.

Comment: `matriz2= (float**) malloc (sizeof(float**));` --> `matriz2= (float**) malloc (36*sizeof(float*));`, `matriz2[m]= malloc(36*sizeof(float*));` --> `matriz2[m]= malloc(36*sizeof(float));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
matriz2= (float**) malloc (sizeof(float**));
for (int m=0;m<36;m++) {
    matriz2[m]=(float *) malloc(36*sizeof(float*));
}
```

reserves space for only one pointer, but assigns 36 pointers and therefore exceeds array bounds and yields undefined behaviour (crash, "funny" output, ...).

Generally you are mixing up the pointers to pointers to floats semantics in your code (e.g. `matriz2= (float**) malloc (sizeof(float**))` should be `matriz2= (float**) malloc (36*sizeof(float*))`).

Let's start from a single dimension. If you allocate space for a sequence of 36 float values, you will write `malloc(36 * sizeof(float))`. The result of this will be a pointer to the first float value of this sequence, and the type of the result is therefore `float *` (BTW: in contrast to C++, in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`). Note that - for getting a sequence of float values, you write `36 * sizeof(float)`, and not `36 * sizeof(float*)`, which would be a sequence of pointers to floats. Hence, a single dimension is allocated as follows:

```
float *row = malloc(36 * sizeof(float));
```

If you now have a sequence of such rows (each having type `float *`), you need to allocate space for a sequence of such pointers, i.e. `malloc (36 * sizeof(float*))`, and the result is a pointer to the first pointer of this sequence of pointers. Hence, the result type is `float**`:

```
float **matrix = malloc(36 * sizeof(float*))
```

Then you can reserve space for each row and assign it:

```
float **matrix = malloc(36 * sizeof(float*))  // sequence of pointers to rows
for (int m=0;m<36;m++) {
    matrix[m]=malloc(36*sizeof(float));  // row, i.e. sequence of floats
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

your initial malloc is too small (35 times :))